Snowflake Connector Returns Server Error 504 Gateway Timeout, when hosted on Kubernetes
We have a system that runs on AKS (Azure Kubernetes Services) where one of our deployment hosts Python code that connects to Snowflake using the following connection:

import os
import snowflake.connector

def create_snowflake_connection(account, access_token, warehouse, database, user, role):
    conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
        user=user,
        host=os.getenv('SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT'),
        token=access_token,
        role=role,
        account=account,
        warehouse=warehouse,
        database=database,
        authenticator='oauth',
        client_session_keep_alive=True,
        max_connection_pool=100,
    )

    return conn

Now when we call that deployment to run a set of queries (function_name); it returns a Server Error 504 Gateway Time-out for url https://url-of-deployment.com/endpoint/function_name
However, when the same python code is run directly from the machine of the user; without using kubernetes, the code works just fine.
So, we tried to troubleshoot the issue and see where is the cause; from both kubernetes and snowflake connection configurations.
1. Snowflake connection troubleshoot results:
1.a Snowflake Connector Version:
snowflake-connector-python==3.12.0
1.b Increase Snowflake Connection Timeout Parameters:
We tried to increase these parameters using this documentation below:
Managing Snowflake Connection Timeout
like the following

import os
import snowflake.connector

def create_snowflake_connection(account, access_token, warehouse, database, user, role):
    conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
        user=user,
        host=os.getenv('SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT'),
        token=access_token,
        role=role,
        account=account,
        warehouse=warehouse,
        database=database,
        authenticator='oauth',
        client_session_keep_alive=True,
        max_connection_pool=100,
        login_timeout=300,
        network_timeout=300,
        socket_timeout=300
    )

    return conn

But still getting the same error when calling the endpoint. It seems actually that increasing the value of socket_timeout in the python connector code does not actually affect the default value of DEFAULT_SOCKET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT found in:
Python Snowflake Connector Network.py
according to this post:
Github Snowflake Timeout Issue Post
2. Kubernetes troubleshoot results:
So, we tried also to check the manifests of our deployment in kubernetes if it has some timeout config set to 60s; this is because in most cases of the timeout 504 error that we were getting, the logs from kubernetes show that when awaiting_response time beyond 60 seconds; there is a timeout error returned.
2.a deployment manifest timeout value:
These are the timeout configs that are set in out deployment manifest:
.
.
.
readinessProbe:
   initialDelaySeconds: 1
   periodSeconds: 2
   timeoutSeconds: 300 # This one was set to 60 seconds and increased to 300 seconds
   successThreshold: 1
   failureThreshold: 1
.
.
.
.
nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: 3600s
nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: 3600s
nginx.org/proxy-send-timeout: 3600s

It is also worth noticing that we use an oauth2 reverse proxy pod for authenticating users requests sent to the previous deployment; users authenticate to the oauth2 reverse proxy (associated with an app registration); receive an access token, then they send their requests. However, in the manifest we did not set any timeout config value.
I found in kubernetes documentation this setting:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-keepalive-timeout
which defaults to 60 seconds (probably the cuase of our gateway timeout), but I do not understand how it is related to this setting:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-keepalive
the documentation says:
Defaults to 60 and only applied if auth-keepalive is set to higher than 0

yes you can once try setting nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-keepalive to a value greater than 0, and increase the nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-keepalive-timeout and also if necessary, increase the timeout settings in your OAuth2 reverse proxy to prevent it from terminating the connection prematurely. But I feel your problem may be deeper than just timeout settings. Please investigate network performance between the AKS cluster and Snowflake, possibly using tools like kubectl logs, tcpdump, or network policies. Are the pods up?

I am sharing one more approach instead of OAuth2 proxy I am suggesting Flask. Please try this approach and see

In order to connect to your snowflake from AKS, assuming you have pushed your snowflake image to your acr

Create your application file as below-
import os

from flask import Flask, jsonify

import snowflake.connector

import getpass

  

app = Flask(__name__)

  

def create_snowflake_connection():

account = os.getenv('SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT') or input('Enter Snowflake account: ')

user = os.getenv('SNOWFLAKE_USER') or input('Enter Snowflake user: ')

warehouse = os.getenv('SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE') or input('Enter Snowflake warehouse: ')

database = os.getenv('SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE') or input('Enter Snowflake database: ')

role = os.getenv('SNOWFLAKE_ROLE') or input('Enter Snowflake role: ')

access_token = os.getenv('SNOWFLAKE_ACCESS_TOKEN') or getpass.getpass('Enter Snowflake access token: ')

  

conn = snowflake.connector.connect(

user=user,

host=account,

token=access_token,

role=role,

account=account,

warehouse=warehouse,

database=database,

authenticator='oauth',

client_session_keep_alive=True,

max_connection_pool=100,

login_timeout=300,

network_timeout=300,

socket_timeout=300

)

return conn

  

@app.route('/query')

def run_query():

conn = create_snowflake_connection()

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT CURRENT_VERSION()")

result = cursor.fetchone()

cursor.close()

conn.close()

return jsonify(result)

  

if __name__ == "__main__":

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)

Now this is absolutely your choice how you want to put the snowflake credentials. You can either do this way at runtime or can also pass them as secret inside aks or even put them inside deployment as below-
env:
- name: SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT
  value: "snowflake_acc_value"
- name: SNOWFLAKE_USER
  value: "snowflake_username"
- name: SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE
  value: "snowflake_warehouse"
- name: SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE
  value: "snowflake_databasename"
- name: SNOWFLAKE_ROLE
  value: "role"
- name: SNOWFLAKE_ACCESS_TOKEN
  value: "your_snowflake_access_token"

accordingly whichever method you are choosing, update your deployment yaml as below-
apiVersion: apps/v1

kind: Deployment

metadata:

name: snowflake-app

spec:

replicas: 1

selector:

matchLabels:

app: snowflake-app

template:

metadata:

labels:

app: snowflake-app

spec:

containers:

- name: snowflake-app

image: arkorgacr.azurecr.io/snowflake-app:latest

ports:

- containerPort: 5000

readinessProbe:

httpGet:

path: /query

port: 5000

initialDelaySeconds: 1

periodSeconds: 2

timeoutSeconds: 300

successThreshold: 1

failureThreshold: 1

imagePullSecrets:

- name: acr-auth


and update your ingress as below-
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1

kind: Ingress

metadata:

name: snowflake-app-ingress

annotations:

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "3600"

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-keepalive: "10"

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-keepalive-timeout: "300"

spec:

rules:

- http:

paths:

- path: /

pathType: Prefix

backend:

service:

name: snowflake-app

port:

number: 5000

I don't have any external domain but if you do then update your ingress spec section as below-
spec:
  rules:
  - host: snowflake-app.yourdomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: snowflake-app
            port:
              number: 5000


Once you deploy them, you should get your external IP address

which you can use to connect to your snowflake
Reference-
Snowflake connector for Python
access snowflake using flask SO thread
Ingress annotations
